# On right click with pynput

Tags: python, pynput

I'm trying to globally detect a right-click and run an event on that right-click by using pynput's on_click() function.

Here's my code currently:

```
import pynput
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button, Controller

mouse = Controller()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print("Click Detected")

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

This code prints "Click detected" to the console when any mouse button is pressed, such as the middle mouse button or the side mouse buttons. I'm trying to make it so it only prints that when I right click.

I've tried to pass `mouse.Button.right` instead of `button` but it gives me a syntax error and highlights the ".", I've also tried to pass `mouse.Button.right` to the `button` variable by using `button = mouse.Button.right` but it gives me a `AttributeError: 'Controller' object has no attribute 'Button'` error.

If anybody has knowledge of the pynput library or knows what will work for this, that would be great. I'm new to python so any constructive criticism that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to try using mouse library because it is much easier. I think you can do the same thing there with using only one line of code`mouse.is_pressed("right")` if you want to install that library, just use pip install mouse in cmd

Answer (score 0):

Check also if variable 'button' is equal to 'mouse.Button.middle':

```
from pynput import mouse


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if not pressed and button == mouse.Button.middle:
        print("Right Click Detected (released)")


with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```